# How can I prove divisibility using congruence?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I'm new to this, so please excuse me if I said something wrong or offended anyone.
We're doing the number theory in class, and I came across this question, which I had no idea how to even begin..:

Use congruences to prove 5|(n5 − n)
(by the way, we already proved this using induction)

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant exponent, try the following:

$$n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$$

Now check that no matter what $\;n\pmod 5\;$ is, the above is always $\;0\pmod 5\;$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$0^5\equiv 0\mod 5$$
$$1^5\equiv 1\mod 5$$
$$2^5=32\equiv 2\mod 5$$
$$3^5\equiv (-2)^5\equiv -2\equiv 3\mod 5$$

$$4^5\equiv (-1)^5\equiv4\mod 5$$
so we conclude that for all $n$
$$n^5\equiv n\mod 5$$
and the result follows. Notice also that we can find this result using the [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).